# Python venv keep to point to Python 3 although I created from 2.7 in Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-venv

I am trying to configure a framework that works with Python 2. I created venv from Python 2:

```
virtualenv -p c:\Python27\python.exe venv
```

When I check it:

```
(venv) C:\Dev\my\v8\depot_tools>python --version
Python 2.7.17
```

But now when I try to execute it, I'm getting this error:

```
(venv) C:\Dev\my\v8\depot_tools>python tools/git-sync-deps
  File "c:\Python36-64\Lib\site.py", line 177
    file=sys.stderr)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

which points to the python3 that installed on the pc, and yes both:

```
c/Python36-64
c/Python36-64/Scripts
```

are in the PATH var.

Comment: For fun, what do you get if you run python in your venv and in the REPL: `import sys; sys.executable`? It looks like git-sync-deps uses this value to launch "stuff" and if that points to python3 even though you are in a python2 venv then you might need to set/verify `PYTHONEXECUTABLE`

Comment: it keep giving me :(venv) C:\Dev\my\v8\depot_tools\venv\Scripts>python
  File "c:\Python36-64\Lib\site.py", line 177
    file=sys.stderr)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Did you try to verify what `sys.executable` is set to and or did you check for the proper setting of the environment variable `PYTHONEXECUTABLE`?  `sys.executable` might show you where your issue is or might rule out something as a problem. I suspect that even though you are in a python2 venv, this variable is still pointing to the default python that is your python 3.

Comment: i type python and it gives me what i copy paste before